# MVVM What to use? Windows phone 8

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have A design Issue Question here i have seen MVVM light implementation and a very simple Micorsoft example of MVVM for windows phone [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830877.aspx), Now the question is what is the ideal way going forward

MVVM Light or Very Simple Microsoft way ( as link above) , the Application developing is Long term (enterprise kind) use, i need to decide which way to go ,  i am little confused between pros and cons

1. if i have 6 pages, which is the better way to use?
2. how easily can i access  common data of another ViewModel in case of Simple MS way, with MVVM
   light we can have IOC services.
3. how can i handle Application Activation or Deactivation events ?
4. which has the better Performance and faster?
5. Lesser Code Complexity and maintenance for anyone who looks into the app for the first time?

So please Some one help me getting answers or understand things.Would Really appreciate Your HELP!!!

Comment: As it stands, this question is a bit open ended. Can you refine your question a bit?

Comment: its just that what should i use MVVM light or Simple MS way (as in case of link)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First things first, [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) is a framework that helps with getting started with the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). You don't need to use MVVM Light to implement the MVVM pattern, it just makes parts of it much easier.

So it kind of invalidates a couple of your questions, but as I'm in the process of finishing off my WP8 app using MVVM Light, i'll answer them assuming you use that framework (I recommend it).

1. 6 pages are easily handled. You should look and learn how to use the ViewModelLocator and Messaging to decouple pages, navigation and their associated view models
2. I have used Ninject to do IOC/DI in my ViewModelLocator.
3. This is a bit fiddly, but I think it's ok to break the MVVM pattern in this case as these methods are in the App.xaml.cs
4. MVVM performance is obviously going to be a bit slower, but unless you are doing things poorly, you will NEVER notice it. It's worth remembering that the app will always run faster when the debugger is not attached as well.
5. I think MVVM is a great pattern for keeping a good separation of concerns and responsibilities.

I know this doesn't actually answer your question, but your question doesn't make sense in light of what I mentioned earlier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: one more Question How can Handle Data Validation Part?

Comment: google "data validation MVVM". There are plenty of articles on how to do it. also look around for "data validation windows phone"